# Show each result one by one

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, while-loop

I have a code which increases a URL parameter in a `while` loop until `$i` is equal to 10. When this happens, it will display each number up to 10 (as this is when `$i` stops increasing) - in this case it would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

The problem with this is that only when `$i` is equal to 10 does it show 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 - I need it to display the numbers as it happens (rather than waiting for `$i` to equal 10!).

```
<div id="here"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test2.php",
            success: function(data) { $("#here").html(data);  }
        });
});
</script>
```

test2.php:

```
while($content = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com?id='.$i)) {
   if($i !== 10) {
      echo $i;
   }else{
      break;
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: How long does your script take to run when you run it in a browser?

Comment: @Akshay Literally only a few seconds. However this is an example - I can have `$i` going up to 10000 and that does take a while. I have also condensed the code down.

Comment: if your interval is the same, just use the $interval or $timeout

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively request each file in sequential order using `.queue()`, `.append()`

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

$({}).queue("ajax", $.map(arr, function(item, i) {
  return function(next) {
    return $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "test2.php",
              data: {n:item}
           })
           .then(function(data) { 
             $("#here").append(data);  
             next();
           });

  }
})).dequeue("ajax")
```

php

```
if (isset($_POST["n"])) {
  $content = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com?id=" . $_POST["n"]);
  echo $content
}
```

Comment: @bobjomes jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uL9jc0jb/ , chaining `.promise().then()` to call function when all functions within queue are complete https://jsfiddle.net/uL9jc0jb/1/

Comment: How would I increase the number of requests?

Comment: @bobjomes _"How would I increase the number of requests?"_ You can add items to `arr` array

Comment: No I mean like at the moment it goes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 e.g How do I like run two items at the same time to speed it up

Comment: @bobjomes That is a slightly different Question, though possible. Would have to adjust `$.ajax()` calls to perform two at a time, though since each call requests a different file, not certain if process would be faster. Note original Question is _"Show each result one by one"_ not two at a time

Comment: I see, ok thank you. Does the process restart once its finished?

Comment: The process can be restarted. Though presently, no, the process should be complete when queue is empty.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically restart the process once it's finished?

Comment: You can recursively call a function which returns the promise when the queue complete using pattern at https://jsfiddle.net/uL9jc0jb/1/, see https://jsfiddle.net/uL9jc0jb/3/

Comment: @bobjomes Version where recursion can be stopped by `click` event https://jsfiddle.net/uL9jc0jb/6/

Comment: When I use the recursively call, I get the error `jquery-1.12.4.js:357 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: What about automatically refreshing the page when it gets to the end?

Comment: Yes, you can reload page at when queue is empty by chaining `.promise("ajax").then(function(){location.reload()})` to `javascript` at Answer

Comment: so after `})).dequeue("ajax")`?

Comment: @bobjomes Yes. `.dequeue("ajax").promise("ajax").then(function(){location.reload()})`

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: I fixed it by changing it to `})).dequeue("ajax").promise("ajax").then(function(){location.reload()})`

Comment: Hello again, I have had no internet due to moving. This does not resolve my problem as it would take me forever to write out 1 to 100000 in the `var arr`. With my original code, the number increased by 1 each time.

Comment: @bobjomes _"This does not resolve my problem as it would take me forever to write out 1 to 100000 in the `var arr`."_ Original Question "I have a code which increases a URL parameter in a while loop until $i is equal to 10"_ does not mention _"write out 1 to 100000"_? `arr` was used for example at jsfiddle. Same approach can be used to create and iterate an array containing `1000000` indexes `var arr = new Array(100000);`,  adjusting `$.map()` by substituting current index `i`  for `item` at value at `$.ajax()` e.g., `data: {n:i}` https://jsfiddle.net/uL9jc0jb/7/

Comment: Hello, I've just got back from a holiday in Canada. How would I automatically add one to `$_POST['n']` each request rather than having to create an array?

Comment: @bobjomes _"How would I automatically add one to $_POST['n'] each request rather than having to create an array?"_ What is maximum number of requests that should be made? What is issue with using an array to set maximum number of requests?

Answer (score 0):

There is no stable way to have a PHP script generate output until the script ends.

If you need a countdown, you can put the while loop in your Javascript and have it call the PHP script with something like:

```
test2.php?i=1
```

then

```
test2.php?i=2
```

etc.

Comment: Is it possible to do it if the code is fully written in JS?

Comment: Or Node.js? Would that do it?

Comment: It's not a limitation of PHP but the API that the web servers use to communicate with PHP.  PHP itself will generate output as soon as it hits the print statements in the code.  Normally, there is good reason to do this, you don't want incomplete HTML tags sent to the browser.

Comment: @bobjomes Yes, see my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

I really think `async` would help you here. Could you maybe try this code ?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test2.php",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) { $("#here").html(data);  }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @bobjomes
No issues. Just let me know if it helped you or not.